# React returning <td>'s

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I have a very simple React code, which works properly:

```
function Columns(){
    return (
      <React.Fragment>
        <li>Hello</li>
        <li>World</li>
      </React.Fragment>
    );
  }
  function Example(){
    return (
      <div>
      <ul>
      <Columns />
      </ul>
      </div>
    )
  }
  ReactDOM.render(<Example />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

What is wrong with the following example, which seems to not return a thing:

```
function Columns(){
    return (
      <React.Fragment>
        <td>Hello</td>
        <td>World</td>
      </React.Fragment>
    );
  }
  function Example(){
    return (
      <div>
        <table>
          <tr>
            <Columns />
          </tr>
        </table>           
      </div>
    )
  }
  ReactDOM.render(<Example />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

I just can't see any differences from the React documentation which pretty much gives the exact example [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/fragments.html)

Comment: It seems to work fine https://codesandbox.io/s/zq9xk1nqrl . Inspect the dom and you'll find the td's.

Comment: be sure that you have all imports, like :
```import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';```

Comment: @VladimirBogomolov that's very interesting. It wasn't working on codepen when I was playing around with it, and now I just copy-pasted it, and it started working. Must've been some issue with codepen itself not refreshing or something.

Comment: @ravibagul91 not really, if I wanted to use <Fragment></Fragment> then I would need to import, since I'm using it as <React.Fragment>, there's no need to write the import line. At least that's what the documentation says.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's already there, you just don't see borders because they are transparent :)

```
function Columns() {
  const style = { border: "solid 1px black" };
  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      <td style={style}>Hello</td>
      <td style={style}>World</td>
    </React.Fragment>
  );
}
```

https://3rpyml13wm.codesandbox.io/

Answer (score -1):

- Use class instead of fonctions
- import React and ReactDom
- import Fragment

```
    import React, { Component, Fragment } from 'react';
    import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

    class Example extends Component
    {

        render() {
            return (
                ...
                <Columns />
                ...
            );
        }
    }

    class Columns extends Component
    {
        render() {
            return (
                ...
            );
        }
    }

   ReactDOM.render(<Example />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

Comment: From [Functional vs Class-Components in React](https://medium.com/@Zwenza/functional-vs-class-components-in-react-231e3fbd7108) article: "If you need a state in your component you will either need to create a class component or you lift the state up to the parent component and pass it down the functional component via props". Do I need a state here, can you elaborate why should this make a difference?

Comment: Dont listen to @Laurent. You never want to use React.Component instead of function component if you aren't  using lifecycle methods.

Answer (score -1):

Maybe the problem is in `import`s.

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
```